# Hough Circles in OpenCV3.0 vs OpenCV 2.3.1

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform

I have an input image with 4 circles and I want to use HoughCircles function in OpenCV to identify the circles. I'm using C++ version of OpenCV on a Windows x64 machine. Below is the pseudo-code that I used for circle detection:

```
Read input image
Convert it from RGB to Gray scale
Gaussian blur
HoughCircles
```

I tried the above pseudo-code in OpenCV 2.3.1 and OpenCV 3.0. Even though I used the same parameters for Gaussian blur and HoughCircles, OpenCV version2.3.1 identified only 3 circles while version3.0 correctly identified 4 circles. I understand from the changelog that version 3.0 has a new algorithm for HoughCircles but I don't know enough about the method to understand what has changed.

Is the behavior am seeing an expected one? Is HoughCircle detection in OpenCV2.3.1 inferior to that of OpenCV3.0?

Comment: HoughCircles gives different result all the time,I would recommend you to find the contours and from that contour you can check if it is circle or not.